# NFC Acr122u-A2 read

Tags: java, nfc

I have a ACR122u-A2 Smartcard reader and mifare classic 1k cards. I was wondering how to read these cards through a java program. I have been searching but the answers i get were not clear to me. The cards store NDEF message.

Comment: What did you try? What was your understanding of these answers you got? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [NFC Tools for Java](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools). Also, you might be interested in this [NDEF editor plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) to explore the NDEF format some more (shameless plug).